# Афганская война как пишется? С прописной или строчной?

Tags: прописная-строчная, прописная

Афганская война как пишется? С прописной или строчной? На Грамоте разночтения...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно такие наименования пишутся со строчной буквы, но **Афганская война** — исключение и пишется *с прописной*.

[Источник: Грамота.Ру со ссылкой на словарь-справочник](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=282738).

Comment: Полезный вопрос и полезный ответ.  А в словаре (или где-нибудь) не написано, почему это исключение?

Comment: @Sharon я не нашёл. На Грамоте есть ранний ответ (очевидно, данный ещё до выхода словаря-справочника), где "афганская" упоминалась в ряду "локальных военных конфликтов последних десятилетий" и писалась со строчной буквы. Да и по Нацкорпусу если посмотреть — преимущественно со строчной буквы, но там источники в основном до 2004 примерно года. Зато много упоминаний Афганской войны в виде "Афган" — именно войны, а не государства (полагаю, можно считать метонимией). Возможно, это и повлияло на рекомендацию писать Афганскую войну с прописной.

Comment: Спасибо, я поняла. Интересно было прочитать дополнительную информацию.  На каком-то этапе нарицательное название переходит в собственное, а переход фиксируется в словаре. Вот этот момент, конечно,  интересен.